# How to convert Rice Distribution to Rayleigh Distribution?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

We know that if

```
x \[Distributed] ExponentialDistribution[λ]
```

then

```
y = Sqrt[x] \[Distributed] RayleighDistribution[1/Sqrt[2*λ]]
```

Which we can justify by the following:

```
Dist = RayleighDistribution[1/Sqrt[2*λ]];
SDist = TransformedDistribution[x^2, x \[Distributed] Dist]
```

On the other hand, we also know that if

```
r \[Distributed] RiceDistribution[0, σ]
```

then

```
r \[Distributed] RayleighDistribution[σ]
```

But by the following code, I do not get an Exponential Distribution. Why?

```
Dist = RiceDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[2*λ]];
SDist = TransformedDistribution[x^2, x \[Distributed] Dist]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dist = RiceDistribution[0, 1/Sqrt[2*λ]];

SDist = TransformedDistribution[x^2, x \[Distributed] Dist];
```

Compare the `PDF`s for `SDist` and `ExponentialDistribution`

```
PDF[SDist, x] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

```
PDF[ExponentialDistribution[λ], x]
```

[image]

While functionally equivalent, the `PDF`s differ (a difference that is negligible since it has measure zero) is that the `PDF` for `SDist` is not defined for `x==0`. This difference arises because the `PDF` for the `RiceDistribution` is not defined for `x==0`

```
PDF[Dist, x]
```

[image]